# Ruby syntax to loop through items, take a count, then act on the result ... not working

Tags: ruby

I have some ruby that I am passing a web control (dropdownlist).  My intent is to count the number of listitems that are selected, and if that count is > 1, deselect the first item in the drop down list.

This is what I have so far .. it doesn't break, but count always comes out as 0, even when I force the more items to selected.

```
return control if control.nil?;

count = 0;
control.Items.each { |item| if item.Selected == "true" then count+=1 end }
if count > 1 then
  control.Items[0].Selected = "false"
end
return control;
```

I have tried item.Selected = 1 as well, thinking it was being treated as a bit.  Can someone point out what I have messed up.

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what the expected value of Selected is. Do you perhaps want a boolean `true` rather than the string `"true"`?

Comment: On the web control, its a bool.

Comment: You should be testing for the boolean `true` rather than the string `"true"` in your loop, then. They aren't equivalent.

Comment: I'm trying that now .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Still using your "string boolean":

```
unless control.nil?
  if control.Items.select { |item| item.Selected == "true" }.count > 1 then
    control.Items[0].Selected = "false"
  end
end

return control;
```

Using a real boolean:

```
unless control.nil?
  control.Items[0].Selected = false if (control.Items.select { |item| item.Selected }.count > 1)
end

return control;
```

Comment: This looks much cleaner, I will try it as well.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A tiny refactor to mbranch snippet:

```
if control 
  control.Items[0].Selected = false if control.Items.count(&:Selected) > 1
end
control
```

Im using `if control` because `unless control.nil?` will be `true` if `control` is `false` and I don't think `FalseClass` is supposed to have a method called `Items`.

`count` accepts a block as an argument and it will increment the counter for each item in the array for wich the block returns `true`. By doing this, you are avoiding a complete iteration over `Items`.

The `&:Selected` is just a "trick" (`&` calls `to_proc` on the symbol and `Symbol#to_proc` returns the method that it references) and it is the same as doing `{ |i| i.Selected }`

Anyway, methods should be written in snake_case not capitalized, then after if is deprecated, etc (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Comment: I like it. I forgot about the `&` notation.